# MongoDB index order for unique value & boolean value

Tags: mongodb, indexing, b-tree

I am a little bit confused about the order of the index in Mongo DB, Based on the MongoDB official website the index should follow https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/equality-sort-range-rule/

but let's say I have 1 million records of **fooID (unique)** and **isActive (true false)**
What index order that I should use?

is it `{ fooID: 1, isActive: 1 }` or `{ isActive: 1, fooID: 1 }`

based on the [mongo book](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=uGUKiNkKRJ0C&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=mongodb%20the%20definitive%20guide%20index%20cardinality&source=bl&ots=h8mzPdcTrl&sig=xJ40rE2qjoSy9RQrvxLnNDx6KS8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=mongodb%20the%20definitive%20guide%20index%20cardinality&f=false), the highest cardinality one should be placed in the first order. but mongoDB is used b-tree with log(n) for searching

so the execution if we used `{ fooID: 1, isActive: 1 }` should like

```
log(1m) + log(1m/2) = 38.8631371386
```

and if we used `{ isActive: 1, fooID: 1 }`
the execution should be

```
log(2) + log(1m/2) = 19.9315685693
```

please correct me if I'm wrong, if the calculation is correct that the isActive take the first order right? which is lower cardinality